# Spring Data JPA: Mark entity as dirty to increase @Version

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am looking for a way to mark an entity as dirty with Spring Data JPA even though no attribute has changed. My goal is that the entity's version (as per `@Version`) is increased and my auditing attributes (`@LastModifiedBy` etc) are updated.

There seems to be something like this for JDO (`JDOHelper.makeDirty`) and maybe even `EntityManager.lock()`, but I couldn't find any way to do this with Spring Data JPA. Any pointers?

Comment: Why do you need to do that though? If it hasn't changed, why pretend that it has?

Comment: Another relevant entity has changed, and the requirements demand that the former entity 's last changed date be refreshed accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>We went with this method in the super class of our Spring Data JPA repositories:</s>

```
@Override
public TYP increaseVersion(TYP typ) {
    em.lock(typ, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
    return typ;
}
```

This only increases the @Version attribute. Spring Data JPA does not update the auditing attributes, sadly.

Correction:

```
@Autowired
private AuditingHandler auditingHandler;

void someMethod() {
    auditingHandler.markModified(entity);
}
```

That seems to work.

Comment: Is there a way to mark parent and all it's child as modified?

Comment: You could experiment with the cascade attribute of the @OneToMany annotation, but I don't think that will work...